# Cytron esp8266 Wifi Shield connect and transmit data to xampp localhost wirelessly

Tags: arduino

I have a project about the automated gate. I'm using Cytron ESP8266 Wifi Shield. I'm using it to transmit and store the ultrasonic data to my xampp localhost port 80.

But there is an error in my code on the client side.

Here is my code:

```
#include <CytronWiFiShield.h>
#include <CytronWiFiClient.h>
#include <CytronWiFiServer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int trigPin = 5;
const int echoPin = 4;
long duration;
int distance;

ESP8266Client client;

const char *ssid = "HRHS";
const char *pass = "06031960";
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 100, 9); //The IP address i got from cmd
ESP8266Server server(80);

const char htmlHeader[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                          "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                          "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                          "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n"
                          "<html>\r\n";

void setup()
{

    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial)
    {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }

    if (!wifi.begin(2, 3))
    {
        Serial.println(F("Error talking to shield"));
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    Serial.println(wifi.firmwareVersion());
    Serial.print(F("Mode: "));
    Serial.println(wifi.getMode()); // 1- station mode, 2- softap mode, 3- both

    Serial.println(F("Start wifi connection"));
    if (!wifi.connectAP(ssid, pass))
    {
        Serial.println(F("Error connecting to WiFi"));
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    Serial.print(F("Connected to "));
    Serial.println(wifi.SSID());
    Serial.println(F("IP address: "));
    Serial.println(wifi.localIP());
    wifi.updateStatus();
    Serial.println(wifi.status()); //2- wifi connected with ip, 3- got connection with servers or clients, 4- disconnect with clients or servers, 5- no wifi
    //clientTest();
    espblink(100);
    server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    //Start of Program

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
    delay(1000);

    // Connect to the server (your computer or web page)
    if (client.connect("192.168.100.9", 80)) //Same local ip address from cmd
    {
        client.print("GET /write_data.php?"); // This
        client.print("value=");               // This
        client.print(distance);               // And this is what we did in the testing section above. We are making a GET request just like we would from our browser but now with live data from the sensor
        client.println(" HTTP/1.1");          // Part of the GET request
        client.println("Host: ");             // IMPORTANT: If you are using XAMPP you will have to find out the IP address of your computer and put it here (it is explained in previous article). If you have a web page, enter its address (ie.Host: "www.yourwebpage.com")
        client.println("Connection: close");  // Part of the GET request telling the server that we are over transmitting the message
        client.println();                     // Empty line
        client.println();                     // Empty line
        client.stop();                        // Closing connection to server
    }

    else
    {
        // If Arduino can't connect to the server (your computer or web page)
        Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
    }

    // Give the server some time to receive the data and store it. I used 10 seconds here. Be advised when delaying. If u use a short delay, the server might not capture data because of Arduino transmitting new data too soon.
    delay(10000);
}



void espblink(int time)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        wifi.digitalWrite(2, wifi.digitalRead(2) ^ 1);
        delay(time);
    }
}

}
```

Hello sorry again. I'm going to update the progress here can?

I have updated the code. Please correct me if I'm able or not to do this

Okay, the shield is connected to wifi. However, still cannot connect to database xampp localhost.

I have searched many on Google  but most os the solutions are using ethernet shield and to webpage, not localhost.

Im stuck here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is c++, not c#

Comment: Sorry about that my bad. Confused a bit between c# and c++

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare a (global) variable *server*, like

`const char server[] = "www.adafruit.com";`

(Like you did in void clientTest() )

Comment: If I'm using localhost, should I put the local IP address?

Comment: Should i put it like this `const char server[] = "192.168.100.5";` i got the ip address from ipconfig

Comment: No, use the IPAddress class instead: `IPAddress server(192, 168, 100, 5);` This is the address where the client connects to. Because you run a server also, it's better to rename _server_ to something like _clientserver_

Comment: You still have the same error message, or is your program not working?

Comment: Did you download the complete map from [github](https://github.com/CytronTechnologies/CytronWiFiShield), including the .cpp files? The function does exists, it should work though.

Answer (score 0):

But I did something else. I made my wifiShield a server itself. I am able to control led from there and monitor the data from there. Unfortunately no data storage but as long  as I can monitor it from distance I am happy lol